# Get the value of a dynamic form field (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have a form which uses dynamic inputs if the user chooses to show a div. I am unable to get the value from the dynamic form field.

Here's an example.

HTML (This div only displays when the user clicks the show DIV link)

```
<form id="myForm">

<input type="text" id="name" />

<a href="#" id="showDiv">Show Div</a>

<div id="newElement" style="display:none;"><input type="text" id="newField"/></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript - Let's assume the user has clicked the "Show Div" link which then shows the newElement div, and then submits the form. Here's the code that runs on submit.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
      alert($('#name').val());
      alert($('#newField').val());
});
```

I receive a value for the first alert, but not the second.

Comment: do you have multiple html elements with id=newField? Asking just in case since you say that you add them dynamically.

Comment: According to your HTML there *is* no value.

Comment: No, just one. I have several dynamic elements on this page and none of them are showing in my examples when using alert. Not sure why my post was down voted?

Comment: This seems to work? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: How is the `newField`s being set? By the user?

Comment: Working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/t6ZaE/

Comment: @Joy Thanks, was going to do this to prove the problem is not in the code above.

Comment: Fresh, yes it's a form.. the user clicks Show Div to change the visibility of the newElement div, and then fills out the newField input.

Comment: @JasonWells, Try to regenerate the problem in the above fiddle link I added. That will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

My DIV was named the same thing as my form field (oops), stupid mistake. Thanks for taking a look though everyone.

Answer (score -1):

You bind the `submit` event on `#myForm` but it doesn't exist yet, so you won't bind anything.

What you should do is use the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$(document).on('submit' , '#myForm', function() {
    alert($('#newField').val());
});
```

This listens on `document` for a submit call on `#myForm`.

**Edit**

This is not the case for this problem, it actually [seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/URwXk/) ?

Comment: hmm, it does exist as my other form fields show just fine? I'm not sure I follow. Perhaps my original code was misleading since I didn't paste the entire form.

Comment: Ah misread the question, you dynamically set the `display` not the element itself

Comment: -1` If `$("#myForm")` exists at DOM creation there is no need for this. That is what the `event` is being attached to not the new input fields.

Comment: @iambriansreed yes, I thought the *element* was dynamically created, not the *visibility*. If the element is dynamically created you would need `on()`

Comment: floorish, the visibility is being adjusted. The element is actually already on my page. I am receiving a "Undefined" in my alert.

Comment: @JasonWells What browser are you using? This works fine in Chrome for me: http://jsfiddle.net/URwXk/

Comment: I'm in Chrome as well, I simplified my example because I have a few other things going on in the page, but perhaps something else is conflicting.

Comment: I think I got it, my DIV was named the same thing as my form field (oops), stupid mistake. Thanks for taking a look though